# Cannot remove directory on NFS client

Tags: nfs

On my desktop, in my home directory which is an autofs NFS mount, I try running:

```
sw@client:~$ rm -fr ~/libraries/receiver/
rm: cannot remove '/home/sw/libraries/receiver/src/arduino/i2c-module/channels': Directory not empty
sw@client:~$ ls -al /home/sw/libraries/receiver/src/arduino/i2c-module/channels
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 sw users 4096 Nov  3 13:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 sw users 4096 Nov  3 13:06 ..
sw@client:~$
```

So `rm -rf` won't delete my directory. If I look on the server, I can see its problem:

```
sw@server:~$ ls -la ~/libraries/receiver/src/arduino/i2c-module/channels/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 sw users 4096 Nov  3 13:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 sw users 4096 Nov  3 13:06 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 sw users 7608 Nov  3 13:06 I2cChannel.hpp
sw@server:~$
```

So there's a file that the client thinks it has deleted, but the server hasn't obeyed. If I wait 10 mins, nothing changes - suggesting it's not a caching problem, unless there's something I've missed.

If I use `vi` on the offending directory on the client, `vi ~/libraries/receiver/src/arduino/i2c-module/channels` I can see the `I2cChannel.hpp`. Then, the `rm` works ok - fixed, until next time. Problem is, it's happening to lots (but not all) directories, eg when I do a `make clean`, so it's messing things up.

Alternatively, I can `touch` the dir. That fixes it too.

Clearly something's getting out of sync between client and server. But, what?

Any ideas, please?

Additional notes:

```
sw@client:~$ mount | grep home
auto.home on /home type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=11,pgrp=1283,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect,pipe_ino=21134)
server:/export/home/sw on /home/sw type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.26.2,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.26.254)

sw@client:~$ uname -a
Linux client 5.15.0-84-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 5 17:16:10 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And on the server:

```
sw@server:~$ uname -a
Linux server 5.10.0-23-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-1 (2023-05-12) i686 GNU/Linux
```

This has been happening for a few months, but I've been working around it, and today I've just got fed up!  It didn't used to happen - I've had this configuration for a while. I upgraded this client's HD to an SSD a few months ago, cloned the root fs - maybe I messed something up?  But everything else has been fine. I'm trying one of the other desktops to see if if it happens elsewhere, so I'll report what I find; it's frequent but intermittent, so conscious that it might not be solid evidence either way.